# How to call functions on mouse click in C using SDL?

Tags: c, generator, sdl, sdl-2, terrain

I'm making a terrain generator and it's all working well. I have `terrain[height][width]` which has numbers as values. Then depending on the number, I change the color. Basically, I have a print function which initializes SDL and then with a couple `for` cycles goes through the array's elements. Then based on the value at each element it changes color and then it prints a little square on the screen. And so on it shifts the location of these squares, etc and it draws the whole pixelated terrain. Now what I want to do is when I click on the terrain, it generates a new terrain which just replaces the old one. This is what I tried doing:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    switch (event.type)
    {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        running = false;
        break;
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        srand(time(0));
        generate(random(20, 52), 55, 40);
        generateCave();
        generateClouds();
        ground();
        printf("click");
        break;
    }
}
```

and in the second `for` I have `SDL_PumpEvents();` so it's responsive. It works except for the new part which is the one with `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. I think that you can see what I wanted to do there but all it did was when I click, it stops responding and dies. What would be a proper way to do this? Also tell me if you need any more of the code. Thanks in advance and perhaps sorry for asking a dumb question.

Comment: Probably some function you call gets stuck and never returns.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically you want an `SDL_MouseButtonEvent` and check if the coords (x, y) are within a range. You can pass the squares as `SDL_Rects`s, something like:

```
static int region_match(const SDL_Rect *rect, int x, int y)
{
    return ((x >= rect->x) && (x <= rect->x + rect->w) && 
            (y >= rect->y) && (y <= rect->y + rect->h));
}

case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    SDL_MouseButtonEvent *mouse = &event.button;

    if (mouse->button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
    {
        if (region_match(rect, mouse->x, mouse->y))
        {
            // Do your stuff
        }
    }
    break;
```